# giza stream.h error fatal

Tags: g++, makefile, fatal-error, moses, giza++

While installing Giza from here:

```
wget http://giza-pp.googlecode.com/files/giza-pp-v1.0.2.tar.gz
```

After I unzip and run "make" I get the following error:

```
Pointer.h:27:20: fatal error: stream.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Anyone knows how I can resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

You should probably get a newer version of the source. According to https://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/, the latest version is 1.0.7.